# Redmine Cron Job Issue

Tags: cron, task, rake, redmine, jobs

I must set a Cron Job on Redmine to automatically manage IMAP fetching. I try to supply as many infos as I can about my environment:

```
Redmine version               3.2.0.stable
Ruby version                  2.1.5-p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
Rails version                 4.2.5
Environment                   production
Database adapter              Mysql2
```

I have installed `luismaia/redmine_email_fetcher` as a plugin, and I have configured it for gmail IMAP. Up to this point I had no error messages and, by trying a test tool on Redmine, I get a success message.

I sum up the plugin configuration on Redmine as it follows:

```
Configuration type: IMAP
Is configuration active? true
Host : imap.gmail.com
Port: 993
SSL? yes
Email username: mailAddress
Password: mailAccountPwd
Folder Name: Inbox
Method for unknown users: accept
```

Now, I must run a Cron Job. At this link:

https://github.com/luismaia/redmine_email_fetcher

I have found  the following:

```
*/5 * * * *   www-data /usr/bin/rake -f /opt/redmine/Rakefile --silent redmine:plugins:email_fetcher:fetch_all_emails RAILS_ENV=production 2>&- 1>&
```

that I personalize as it follows:

```
*/5 * * * *   www-data /usr/bin/rake -f /opt/redmine/Rakefile --silent redmine:plugins:email_fetcher:fetch_all_emails RAILS_ENV=production host=imap.gmail.com username=mailAddress password= mailAccountPwd port=993  --trace
```

Coming to the point: the line above doesn't work; and I've no idea why.

I can add that:

- in `/usr/bin` I see `rake2.1`
- `opt` directory (`/var/opt`) is empty.

I do hope I have explained my issue in a decent way.

Thank you in advance, really.

ps:
I tried also:

```
*/5 * * * *   www-data /usr/bin/rake2.1 -f /var/www/redmine/Rakefile redmine:plugins:email_fetcher:fetch_all_emails RAILS_ENV=production 2>&- 1>&-
```

but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the which command:

```
which rake
```

for me it's in /usr/local/bin and not in /usr/bin

Next try to chdir in your redmine folder before launch the command in the crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /var/www/redmine/ && sudo /usr/local/bin/rake redmine:plugins:email_fetcher:fetch_all_emails RAILS_ENV=production 2>&- 1>&-
```

Hope this can help you.

Cheers,

Luc

Comment: Sure, it does. Thx really again.